# Ruby: How to replace string with regex match in string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

`a = "product[products_colors_attributes][1400877739750][variants_attributes][0]"`

I want to grab the 1400877739750 part of the string and use it in the new value of a

```
a = "product[products_colors_attributes][1400877739750][variants_attributes][0]"

a.sub!("product[products_colors_attributes][1400877739750][variants_attributes][0], ???)

a #<-- variants[1400877739750][size]
```

Comment: Is the `[products_colors_attributes]` text always the same?

Comment: yep it's always product[products_colors_attributes][SOME NUMBER]

Comment: @Edmund is this POST data from a HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

I grab `product[products_colors_attributes]` literally, followed by `[` and capturing 1+ digits and `]`.  Then we match the rest of the line, since we want to replace it all.  Then in our substitution, we can reference our capture group of digits using `\1`.

```
product\[products_colors_attributes\]\[(\d+)\].*
variants[\1][size]
```

[**Demo**](http://www.rubular.com/r/u0weqeUxsi)

---

Also, I'm not versed in Ruby, but it may be easier to find the number and make a new string with the match *rather* then using a substitution.  Here I use a lookahead to find (but not match) `product[products_colors_attributes][`, and then match the 1+ digits.  We can use the value of this match to make a new string (pseudo code: `a = "variants[" . match . "][size]";`).

```
(?<=product\[products_colors_attributes\]\[)(\d+)
```

[**Demo**](http://www.rubular.com/r/WM9KNplU2h)

Comment: Anyone care to elaborate on the -1?  Was it because I wasn't able to provide a Ruby example?  If so, I think that's a little unnecessary.  I gave two options (both with potential to work in Ruby) ***and*** explained the logic behind them.  OP looked like they knew how to handle regex in Ruby, so that wasn't the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby:

```
a = "product[products_colors_attributes][1400877739750][variants_attributes][0]"

id_regex = /product\[products_colors_attributes\]\[(\d+)\].*/
id = a[id_regex, 1]

new_a = "variants[#{id}][size]"
```

Alternate syntax:

```
match = id_regex.match(a)
id = match[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "product[products_colors_attributes][1400877739750][variants_attributes][0]"
md = str.match(/\d+/)
str = "variants[#{md[0]}][size]" if md

puts str

--output:--
variants[1400877739750][size]
```

Or:

```
str = "product[products_colors_attributes][1400877739750][variants_attributes][0]"

pieces = str.split("][")
number = pieces[1]

str = "variants[#{number}][size]"
puts str

--output:--
variants[1400877739750][size]
```